# Provision Shared Secret Key - JavaCard Applet

Tags: javacard

My javacard supports SCP02. What is the correct approach to inject shared 3DES key into my javacard applet ? (To avoid confusion, I am referring to 3DES key in my applet rather than ISD keysets). Or shall the key be generated inside the applet during applet installation through supplied parameters (seed e.g card uid) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is regarding adding/updating the key(s) used for SCP02,

1. the keys are always managed by the associated SD only
2. use PUT KEY command to replace existing key(s) / add new key(s) as per GP specification